# how to catch Terminating app due to uncaught exception: NSArrayM objectAtIndex index 0 beyond bounds for empty array

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

```
    *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '
*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (0x276b2fef 0x35ba6c8b 0x275c5841 0xe78bb 0xfe689 0x2b19e281 0x2b19ebab 0x2aedc981 0x2b19ea63 0x2b19f1b3 0x2afac2df 0x2b1943a7 0x2afa34d7 0x2aecd003 0x2a8eefc1 0x2a8ea7fd 0x2a8ea685 0x2a8ea031 0x2a8e9e1f 0x2a8e3b79 0x27678ffd 0x276766bb 0x27676ac3 0x275c3221 0x275c3033 0x2eff2201 0x2af2f8c9 0x114b59 0x36156aaf)
    libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I have many `[NSArray objectAtIndex]`, I don't know which one makes it crash.
I've writen the debug code below, but still can't catch it. It's in a UITableView, I load more and more cells by pull down the table, then it sometimes crashes.

```
    #import "NSArray+Debug.h"
#import "MLTool.h"

@implementation NSArray (Debug)

- (id)objectAtIndexEx:(NSUInteger)index{
    if (self.count<1) {
        assert(0);
    }

    NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"count=%d,index=%d,info=%@",self.count,index,[self objectAtIndex:index]];
    if ([MLTool isEmptyString:str]
      //  ||str==
        ) {
        assert(0);
    }

    NSLogUTF8(@"break:%@",str);
    return [self objectAtIndex:index];
}
@end
```

Comment: Try using an exception breakpoint. It will pinpoint the line of code which is causing the crash. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html

Comment: @ZeMoon I've thousands of `objectAtIndex` in many loops, and I think it even not crash in the UITableView's source file, so I can't make an breakpoint. It crashes sometimes, and sometimes it's OK.

Comment: ZeMoon recommends you to set a special kind of breakpoint - All Exceptions. it stops execution exactly before the exception occures and shows you the line of code that causes the exception so you don't need to iterate through thousand stops.

Comment: Thanks all. I've solve it by your solution! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095150/symbolic-exception-breakpoint-on-nsrangeexception-raise

Comment: Or if your application is in app store already, you can use third party libraries to help you catch the crashes. for instance test flight or crashlytics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an "exception breakpoint" in xcode to stop your debugging at the moment of the crash and check why it will crash.

For that in the section breakpoint/debug of the left navigator you can tap on the "+" at the bottom-left corner to add an "Exception breakpoint".